# C++ isfproxies_cpp.dll 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location

Tags: c++

When I called method in external DLL it get error "Access violation"

[image]

Disassembly in this position. What happend?
[image]

If I set domain variable as "" it's go next. 
Exception trowing in line - DSSetServerParams(domain, user, password, server);
My code:

```
// ds_api.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//
using namespace std;

#include "ds_api.h"
extern "C"
{
#include "dsapi.h"
}

int main()
{
    char* domain = "xxx";
    char* server = "xxx";
    char* user = "xxx";
    char* password = "xxx";

    printf(">>> in testconnection()\n");
    DSSetServerParams(domain, user, password, server);
    printf(">>> result of set server params... %d\n", DSGetLastError());
    char* result = DSGetProjectList();
    if (result != NULL)
    {
        printf(">>> getProjectList result = %s\n", result);
    }
    else
    {
        printf(">>> last error = %d\n", DSGetLastError());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us the code for `DSSetServerParams`.  If you don't have the code then show us its documentation.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for answer! It is method documentation url - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=kit-dssetserverparams

Comment: `char* domain = "xxx";` -- This is no longer valid C++.  String literals are `const char *`.  If `DSSetServerParams` attempts to write to those string-literals, then the code has undefined behavior.  Provide true, writable character arrays, i..e `char domain[] = "xxx";`

Comment: The point is that `char *` as a parameter type implies that the data you pass to it can be overwritten -- you do not have the source code to `DSSetServerParams` to know if those `char *` are being written to.  That's why you must pass a writable char array, regardless of whether the data is overwritten or not.  Also, if you were to find out that `DSSetServerParams` does write to those arrays, you can't blame IBM -- they will just tell you "read the documentation -- we said the type was `char*`, not `const char *`"

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the good tips. How I can change my code for it's work? I am kettle in C++ yet

Comment: `char[] domain = "xxx"; char[] server = "xxx";  char[] user = "xxx"; char[] password = "xxx";` -- I do not know if that fixes the problem, but at the very least, the arguments you will be passing will be of the correct type.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It is not working.  I did change domain as char domain[256] = "infoserver1:9080";  and got error 0xC0000005